# Git: How to get remote updates without checkout?

Tags: git, git-svn

I'm looking for a way to list all updated files in the remote master branch, similar to `svn log`.

Is that possible in Git?

Thanks,
Christoffer

**EDIT** (Solution):

```
git fetch
git diff --name-status origin/master
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Without a checkout, you can do the `git fetch` and then `git diff <theotherbranch>`. Without a fetch I can't think of anything but web frontend.

Comment: If I would write a script (similar to a web frontend) to perform the operation, how would it work?

Comment: Well, you can ssh to the remote machine and do the same `git diff`.

Comment: Except for, of course, you would use the commit hash instead of HEAD. where commit hash is your local tip of the remote branch.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm... perhaps

```
git fetch
git log origin/master
```

is what you want (it doesn't show list of changed files, but list of commits on remote-tracking branch).

Answer (score 1):

A response to a comment: `If I would write a script (similar to a web frontend) to perform the operation, how would it work?`

```
git fetch
git diff <branchname> > otherbranch.diff
```

Or read git diff's `stdout` directly.